# Recreate a row from xml column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm storing rows created by triggers applied to around 60 tables into a single audit table.

I have an `xml` column where the row is stored in.

How do I recreate a row from random xml data (at the point of querying I don't know the structure of xml stored since all table rows (nodes in this case) are different with different columns)

One entry can look like this

```
<Log>
  <id>2</id>
  <text>232323</text>
  <text1>2323</text1>
  <text2>2323</text2>
  <text3>2323</text3>
  <text4>2323</text4>
  <text5>2323</text5>
</Log>
```

and another entry could look like this

```
<Log>
  <id>3</id>
  <tableName>ExcludeTables</tableName>
</Log>
```

Now when I do select  from logtable where id = 50 I would like to see columns and values in a regular sql server data row format

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support dynamically created column aliases. The only way to achieve this with unknown column names is *dynamically created SQL*.

In this example I create a *mock-up* table and insert two rows.

The first row will return your nodes as key-value pairs.

The second will create a query dynamically to return the result as you need it:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(100),AuditColumn XML)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1,'Row 1'
,N'<Log>
  <id>2</id>
  <text>232323</text>
  <text1>2323</text1>
  <text2>2323</text2>
  <text3>2323</text3>
  <text4>2323</text4>
  <text5>2323</text5>
</Log>')
,(2,'Row 2'
,N'<Log>
  <id>3</id>
  <tableName>ExcludeTables</tableName>
</Log>');
```

--This is the ID you are searching for

```
DECLARE @id INT=1;
```

--The result is a list of key-value pairs

```
SELECT ID
      ,SomeValue
      ,nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,nd.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY t.AuditColumn.nodes('/Log/*') A(nd)
WHERE t.ID=@id;
```

--The result

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| ID | SomeValue | NodeName | NodeValue |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | id       | 2         |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text     | 232323    |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text1    | 2323      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text2    | 2323      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text3    | 2323      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text4    | 2323      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | Row 1     | text5    | 2323      |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

--dynamically created statement

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT  N'SELECT '
          + STUFF(
            (
                (
                SELECT ',''' + nd.value('.','nvarchar(max)') + ''' AS ' + QUOTENAME(nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'))
                FROM @tbl AS t
                CROSS APPLY t.AuditColumn.nodes('/Log/*') A(nd)
                WHERE t.ID=@id
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                ),1,1,''
            )
);
```

--this is the statement

```
PRINT @cmd;

SELECT '2' AS [id],'232323' AS [text],'2323' AS [text1],'2323' AS [text2],'2323' AS [text3],'2323' AS [text4],'2323' AS [text5]
```

--And this is its execution

```
EXEC (@cmd);

+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | text   | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 | text5 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 2  | 232323 | 2323  | 2323  | 2323  | 2323  | 2323  |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, best answer :)

Comment: @AnatolyTrofimov Please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you - best answer*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!